# Galaxy Tab - application get's no GPS Location on network or passive provider

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, galaxy-tab

UPDATE 2: Problem is solved

after I was outside and got a signal with the GPS_PROVIDER, now I have not a problem anymore to get a location fix with the NETWORK_PROVIDER....

I still don't know why the google maps app was able to get a fix before I did that and my app wasn't, but now it works (even after a restart of the galaxy tab) and I'm kind of happy ;)

---

UPDATE: thread title changed, see the edit at the bottom of the post.

I just tried this tutorial ( http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/ ) for getting a GPS-location on a galaxy tab but I don't get any location....

I already tried to use another provider but this doesn't help at all (I tried the GPS_PROVIDER, NETWORK_PROVIDER, PASSIVE_PROVIDER).

the strange thing is that with the official google maps app I get a location. :\

the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml are set as followed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

does anybody know why my application get's no location?

edit:

with the GPS provider I get a fix when I am outside. but I don't understand why I get no location with the NETWORK_PROVIDER or the PASSIVE_PROVIDER.

which provider does the google maps app use if the GPS isn't available?

edit 2:

the code (it's from the tutorial above with some minor changes):

```
package Firstdroid.Tutorial.Gps; 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UseGps extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        // here I choose the location provider:
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); // <---

    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            loc.getLatitude();

            loc.getLongitude();

            String Text = "My current location is: " +

            "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +

            "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude() + " (PROVIDER: " + loc.getProvider() + ")";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

            "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */

}/* End of UseGps Activity */
```

Comment: Could you post your code where you are setting up your locationlistener etc..?  Also, you don't need to request coarse if you request fine; fine handles both network and GPS providers.

Comment: hi, I just saw your comment. so the GPS_PROVIDER works, but I don't understand that the NETWORK_PROVIDER or the PASSIVE_PROVIDER don't work.

oh and I'll add the code in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Does your galaxy tab have a 3G radio and is connected on a network?  If not it will never get a network_provider location.

Also you don't need those two extra loc.getLatitude and loc.getLongitude calls up top, although I would recommend using those to set a variable and use the variable in your output message.  With this you can now just call the GPSData.getLatitude() etc to get the values you need.

```
public class GPSData {
    private static double latitude;
    /**
     * @return the latitude
     */
    public static double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param latitude the latitude to set
     */
    public static void setLatitude(double l) {
        latitude = l;
    }

    private static double longitude;
    /**
     * @return the longitude
     */
    public static double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param d the longitude to set
     */
    public static void setLongitude(double d) {
        longitude = d;
    }

    private static float accuracy;
    /**
     * @return the accuracy
     */
    public static float getAccuracy() {
        return accuracy;
    }

    /**
     * @param f the accuracy to set
     */
    public static void setAccuracy(float f) {
        accuracy = f;
    }

    //Altitude is in feet
    private static double altitude;

    public static void setAltitude (double a) {
        altitude = a;
    }

    public static double getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }


    /**
     * New location listener to be instantiated for getting locational data
     *
     */
    public static class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            setAccuracy(location.getAccuracy());
            setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            //Altitude is in feet
            setAltitude(location.getAltitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: oh it has no sim-card at all.
the only thing the location could be determined is by the wifi I'm connected to I think.
like I said this wouldn't surprise me that much if the google maps app wouldn't get a location fix... :\

Comment: That would be why then. =)  Please accept my answer when you can, so that this can be marked as resolved.

Comment: hi sry I came accidendtly on ENTER and send my post too early ;)

I added some text...

so I would tag the thread as solved, but for me it's just not solved because I get a location on google maps so it must be possible on my app too or not?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll post something that should help momentarily.

Comment: hm that's strange.... now after my GPS test outside I changed the provider to the NETWORK_PROVIDER and I get a fix now....

Comment: Wifi will also do network_provider...I just wouldn't rely on that in your app.

Comment: so even after a restart of the galaxy tab I get now the location with the NETWORK_PROVIDER... I just don't know why this didn't work before for my app but for google maps it did... really strange... it seems like there happend something magical ;)

edit:

oh and thx Kevin! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you turn wifi on? Also, some devices have Assisted GPS, which I forgot about previously, that will also trigger the network_provider.

Comment: no the WIFI was turned on already and I didn't changed that. the only thing I changed just to be sure that the fix is not from the GPS was to turn off the GPS location in the Galaxy Tab settings.